# Bootstrap - Aligning Yes No with Label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and need to resolve the following issue. I have some text that is too long and it fails over improperly. How could I properly break up this LI Label so it sits on the line with the inputs? Is there a Bootstrap class that handles this for me?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>
    <label class="">
      <input class="radio" type="radio" name="check_hate_crime" value="1" required="">Yes</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="">
      <input class="radio" type="radio" name="check_hate_crime" value="0" required="">No</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="check_hate_crime" class="control-label" style="float:left;font-weight:bold !important;">Do you believe you are the victim of a crime because of your race, religion, sexual orientation, handicap, ethnicity or national origin?</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image: Improperly Wrapped Text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to address this is to use `display: table-cell` for your `.list-inline li` instead of `inline-block`.

```
.list-inline li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: I had to add a text-align:left to the label itself but this worked for my needs. Thanks.